# Perl - Multiple condition if statement without duplicating code?

Tags: perl, if-statement

This is a Perl program, run using a terminal (Windows Command Line). I am trying to create an "if this and this is true, or this and this is true" *if* statement using the same block of code for both conditions without having to repeat the code.

```
if ($name eq "tom" and $password eq "123!") elsif ($name eq "frank" and $password eq "321!") {

    print "You have gained access.";
}
else {

    print "Access denied!";
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Simple:

```
if ( $name eq 'tom' && $password eq '123!'
    || $name eq 'frank' && $password eq '321!'
) {
```

(use the high-precedence `&&` and `||` in expressions, reserving `and` and `or` for flow control, to avoid common precedence errors)

Better:

```
my %password = (
    'tom' => '123!',
    'frank' => '321!',
);

if ( exists $password{$name} && $password eq $password{$name} ) {
```

Comment: @mpapec: no.  the errors I referred to don't apply here, but it's a good general rule.

Comment: I thought @Romiox had a good point; wish that post weren't deleted.

Comment: @ysth I did not get the `&&` vs `and` part.

Comment: @mpapec: in general, in an expression where you want a boolean result, use `&&` and `||`.  if you use `and` and `or`, you are more likely to make mistakes.

Comment: @Rob avoiding a warning if the name doesn't have a password

Comment: @ysth Thanks! I never do checks like this, and I've never gotten any warnings. Is there any reason why I should do this besides avoiding these warnings?

Comment: @Rob: perhaps you don't enable warnings (which you certainly should do).  even better is making warnings fatal.

Answer (score 4):

I don't recommend storing passwords in a script, but this is a way to what you indicate:

```
use 5.010;
my %user_table = ( tom => '123!', frank => '321!' );

say ( $user_table{ $name } eq $password ? 'You have gained access.'
    :                                     'Access denied!'
    );
```

Any time you want to enforce an association like this, it's a good idea to think of a *table*, and the most common form of table in Perl is the hash.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (   ($name eq "tom" and $password eq "123!")
    or ($name eq "frank" and $password eq "321!")) {

    print "You have gained access.";
}
else {
    print "Access denied!";
}
```

Comment: Well, actually I was hardcoding passwords. It wasn't for anything important, just a project.